How can I typeset/include a remote racket file in scribble documentation?
I have a racket file; I would like to typeset it as part of a scribble document, using codeblock formatting. Is there a built-in way to do this?

This is one of those problems you think you need special support for, but is actually super-simple. If the remote file is stored at (say) /tmp/foo.rkt, you can run
#lang scribble/manual

@(require racket/file)

@(typeset-code (file->string "/tmp/foo.rkt"))

... to typeset the file.
